# SQLite3 pragma synchronous not persistent

Tags: sqlite, pragma

I am using an SQLite3 database i WAL-mode. The default mode for pragma statement synchronous is 2 (full), but this makes inserts really slow and according to [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous) 1 (normal) should be fine.

Changing synchronous mode works as long as the database is open, but seems to reset when the connection is ended:

```
root@linux:~# sqlite3 mydb.db
SQLite version 3.8.6 2014-08-15 11:46:33
sqlite> pragma synchronous;
2
sqlite> pragma synchronous=1;
sqlite> pragma synchronous;
1
sqlite>[exit]
root@linux:~# sqlite3 mydb.db
SQLite version 3.8.6 2014-08-15 11:46:33
sqlite> pragma synchronous;
2
```

Nothing else is using the database. Can anyone tell me how to make this change persistent?

Also, what is the difference between setting `pragma synchronous` and `pragma [database name].synchronous`? Neither is persistent, by the way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like most other PRAGMAs, this setting applies not to the database but to the database *connection*.

It cannot be made persistent. You have to make it whenever you open the database.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I assumed it was something like that. Strange that it is not mentioned in the documentation though.